# Right indent of the selection in HTML

Tags: html, css, selection, textselection

Faced the problem, there is an indent on the right side of the selected text in Chrome and Mozilla. Safari doesn't have such.

Checked other sites and it seems to be a default browser behaviour.

Is anyone aware about how to get rid of it?

Sandbox example: https://codepen.io/Steep1692/pen/Yzxvgdz

`<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa architecto natus modi saepe dolore nihil earum nostrum vero molestias nesciunt minima quis culpa, dolores excepturi error nemo! Impedit, beatae enim!</div>`

`div { width: 200px; border: 1px solid green; }`

Pictures examples are below:

The problem is in the differing side indents. They annoys the client.
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a working snippet so we could help you.

Comment: @Azy, yes, I've added sandbox to the question.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? What problem are you trying to solve, is anything not working?

Comment: Seems that is how browsers treats whitespaces on end of line. But what exactly you want to solve here? Try looking into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: The problem is in the differing side indents. They annoys the client.

Comment: @cloned, The problem is in the differing side indents. They annoys the client. Added picture example for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`overflow:hidden`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

> The overflow property specifies what should happen if content
> overflows an element's box.
>
> This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars
> when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green; 
  text-align: justify;  
  text-align-last: left;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa architecto natus modi saepe dolore nihil earum nostrum vero molestias nesciunt minima quis culpa, dolores excepturi error nemo! Impedit, beatae enim!</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for inline elements. But, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work for inline elements ? What do you mean ? Overflow only work with element that have a width/height

Comment: You are right. By the way, it turned out, overflow:hidden can be applied in my case. Found a place to put it. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use text-align justify, but of course that comes with its own peculiarities and issues.

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green; 
  text-align: justify;  
  text-align-last: left;
  overflow: hidden  /* if you dont want it to overlap the boundaries */
}
```

I don't think I've ever seen such a minimal code fiddle on stack overflow, lol. If you can reduce your problem down to this little markup, I would consider that your client is just unhappy with how HTML renders text in general. :P

[image]

Comment: The problem is seen when selection is applied. Updated the question with the screenshot of the problem. Yes, seems it can't be fixed. It leaves when apply tiny lette-spacing, but it obviously brokes the font displaying.

Comment: Oh, just add   'overflow: hidden'   to the div CSS.

Comment: Thx. Although, unfortunately, It does work for inline elements, those the application uses, it can resolve the issue.

Comment: It turned out, overflow:hidden can be applied in my case. Found a place to put it. Thank you once more.